# Fixed bootstrap row over another row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a row at the very top of a page, and another row hovering the previous one. The idea is to create two columns in the first row - `col-md-3` and `col-md-9`, and the second row is to apply an image between those two, so the row has `col-md-2`, `col-md-2` (image between), `col-md-8`. It should look like this:

[image]

I managed to create it, but the box between is still not fixed:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%;">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center; z-index: 9999;">
            <div style="background-color: red;"> # Adding position: fixed here works but breaks box width
               <img src="/assets/image/logo.jpg">
               <br>
               Something
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-8"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="position: relative;">
         <div>
            <img src="/assets/image/leftImage.jpg">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         Lorem ipsum...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use bootstrap, You can use css:

```
div.container
{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
}
div.img
{
  margin:auto;
  width:80%;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

If you check the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L7ww3d7q/3/) you can understand it better.